# Purchase an item repeatedly through google wallet in android

Tags: android, android-pay

I am working on an app in which I need to purchase available tickets for a specific time e.g. a ticket with time of 4pm-8pm for price $5. I tried to integrate google in app purchase but It does now allow to purchase and purchased item. Please let me know if it is possible through google wallet or suggest me an alternative way.

Comment: You can write one more java app with Google Play Developer API. Add purchasable item programmatically.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

Comment: Thanks @MetehanToksoy, you mean to say is as soon as the ticket is purchased I should add a same ticket with diff id in play store and next that id will be used to purchase?

Comment: You will try it on your test device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending so much time on this, I found this solution. I can get the old purchases by this

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
```

And then I can consume the items and let them free for next purchase. To consume items

```
int response = mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), token);
```

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html